# Flash Playhead Going to Wrong Scene, No Explainable Cause

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scene

Every now and then Flash does something unusual, even with something as simple  as a little scene navigation. The problem is that instead of going to the "PitOne" scene as directed on the first scene, the Flash playhead oddly enough arrives on our "LevelOne" scene. This puzzles me, because I can't figure out what could possibly alter the path of the Flash playhead.

**On the last line of the first scene I directly tell Flash to go to our "PitOne" Scene**, which means that even if there are any other navigation methods called before, only this last one should be executed.

Besides this, **there are no eventListeners added on the first scene**, other than some mouse click events. However, since immediately after exporting the Flash movie we are immediately brought to the dreaded "LevelOne" scene, we can assume that these eventListeners have nothing to do with our problem.

I set a trace method on each scene to track the encounters of our Flash playhead. According to the traced output, Flash only enters the first scene and the "LevelOne" scene, so we go directly from the first scene to the "LevelOne" scene. This means that if there is a problem on my part, it's on the first Scene. **But what could possibly alter our scene navigation path in the scenario I've just described to you?** If you have any possible ideas of what it could be, please tell me! Thank you for your time.

**Additional Info:**
Perhaps it might help if I tell you that whenever I return to the first scene the scene navigation code seems to kick in and starts working, because then we are sent to the "PitOne" scene.

I also realize that if you're like me, you'll want to see the real code at hand. Here's the significant code for the first scene (we know that the problem is on the first scene because it's this scene that launches us directly to the "LevelOne" scene):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Scene;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

stop();


playNewBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playNew);
function playNew(e:MouseEvent){
    playNewBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playNew);
    settingsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSettings);
    creditsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoCredits);
    gotoAndPlay(1,"LevelOne");
}

settingsBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSettings);
function gotoSettings(e:MouseEvent){
    playNewBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playNew);
    settingsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSettings);
    creditsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoCredits);
    gotoAndPlay(1,"Settings");
}

creditsBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoCredits);
function gotoCredits(e:MouseEvent){
    playNewBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playNew);
    settingsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSettings);
    creditsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoCredits);
    gotoAndPlay(1,"Credits");
}


gotoAndPlay(1,"PitOne");
```

Comment: Post all code that changes the scene in your project. Do not assume what should or shouldn't matter, because after all, you assume your code should behave differently. the simple answer is: do not use scenes, they always cause trouble and nobody actually uses them. (for that reason)

Comment: True enough, if it helps I'll show my code (obviously not all of it, because that would be thousands of lines of code). Unfortunately, it's a little to late to avoid using scenes now, so I must do the best with what I've got @null

Comment: you should test if scene "Pitone" is loaded before trying to access it

Comment: how can I do that? And @scraaappy respond with an answer not a comment so I can award you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you throw the command before scene is loaded. Whatever you try, (by adding a listener wich check if scene is loaded) the flash player will stay at scene 1 frame 1 until scene "pitOne" is loaded. 
That's why a good practice is to create a preloader to insure you all you need is correctly loaded before throwing command to go somewhere in the timeline. You have simple and well explained sample here : http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/. 
Another solution for you is to set your scene "pitOne" at first position when you export your movie

Answer (score 2):

*This is not an answer but cramping all this into a comment is tedious and not very readable.*

Maybe you have a typo in one of the scenes names?

Try to run this code to get a list of all scenes:

```
import flash.display.Scene;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < scenes.length; i++) {
    var scene:Scene = scenes[i];
    trace("scene " + scene.name + ": " + scene.numFrames + " frames");
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#scenes

---

The way you create Strings does not appear to be valid:

```
trace("entered "settings"");
```

should be

```
trace("entered settings");
```

If you want to include the " in the output, you have to escape them via \" or simply use ' instead.

In your code the " before `settings` marks the end of the string, instead of being a character of the string.

---

If you have "thousands of lines" it might be because of the amount of duplicated code.

```
function disableButtons():void
{
    playNewBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playNew);
    settingsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoSettings);
    creditsBtn.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoCredits);
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean @null, but to be honest I'm not to concerned at the moment with finding the most effective way to go about that, I just tossed up those eventlisteners and functions as rough code before I get further involved in those lesser used scenes. You might call it "Place Holder" code, merely to set a foundation for the more advanced button code I'll be using in the future. For now, I'm merely concerned with being able to cut to the exact scene that I'm developing. I'm pretty sure I've got the scene names right, but I'll double check with your code. Thanks for the help

Comment: output result from your code:                                                           scene Index: 1 frames
scene Settings: 1 frames
scene Credits: 1 frames
scene LevelOne: 1 frames
scene PitOne: 1 frames

Comment: The scene names are correct, it must be something else

Comment: @DrakeSwartzy yes, but I don't know what it could be. sorry. All your scenes are just one frame. I'd suggest putting all the frames into one time line as a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for your dedicated help @null. However, I'd like to ask you a quick question if that's alright, it may help me solve my problem: Why do you avoid scenes? Have you had a bad experience with them in the past or do you just find them difficult to work with? It seems like I've heard some one else tell me at one point that scenes can prove to be finicky at times.

Comment: @DrakeSwartzy I only ever heard of scenes in the context of someone having problems with them. I never worked with them. Instead of `gotoAndPlay()` to a specific scene, you one can always put the content of the scene into an MC and add/removeChild that MC instead. That's why I never had a reason to use scenes.